# bootstrap modal not working in asp.net listview control

Tags: asp.net

I have links in listview. When a link is clicked, i want to show a bootstrap modal to play youtube video but this is show modal of first link when every link is clicked. Video address is saved in database. This is my code.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="760" height="428"  src="<%# Eval("Embeded code") %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy and paste the code below in your solution:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class ListViewAndModalExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var v1 = new Video { VideoName = "CRASHING DRONES AND WRECKING LAMBOS", VideoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/AAmrIVa7UyA" };
            var v2 = new Video { VideoName = "FIRST EVER BOOSTED BOARD 2!!!", VideoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/rdNWP6sBgCk" };
            ListView1.DataSource = new List<Video> { v1, v2 };
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

public class Video
{
    public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public string VideoName { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".videoLink").click(function () {

                var link = $(this);
                var url = $(link).data('url');

                $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
                $("#myModal").modal('show');

            })

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="#" class="videoLink" data-url='<%# Eval("VideoUrl") %>'><%# Eval("VideoName") %></a><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </form>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="420" height="345"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: Displaying YouTube videos using ListView and bootstrap modal popup]

Comment: I have saved video url in database but this method uses hard coding.This method is suitable for small amount of videos but not for large amount of videos

Comment: I have solved problem by converting datatable into list

Comment: how to do same thing in asp.net mvc?

Comment: You need to learn how to use ASP.NET MVC and how to pass a model from a controller to the view.Then use a loop to construct the table displaying the list of videos and the javascript will stay exactly the same for both MVC and web forms.Do some asp.net MVC tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes around the src like this...

```
src='<%# Eval("Embeded code") %>'
```

If that doesn't work then post the code that is generating the link to YouTube.

Comment: <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wJWj7rGj3uY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: I guess you're just missing the http or https at the beginning of your src e.g. https://youtube.com/embed/wJWj7rGj3uY